# .PNG Images Accepted by PictureBox in C#?

Tags: c#, image, png, picturebox, bmp

I am attempting to add a .PNG image to a PictureBox, but it does not seem to be reading it.

```
public static String NoteImage_path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Notes-Images\";
ImageLocation = NoteImage_path + "test" + ".png";
```

With this exact code, I had no issues adding a .BMP file, so why is there an issue with the .PNG file?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer  not an error, but a red x shows up on screen, meaning the image is not found.

Comment: This means that the picture is not in the directory. Try to set a breakpoint at the `ImageLocation` and have a look at the directory.

Comment: as a workaround i would recommand Bitmap. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer is bitmap similar to  picturebox?

Comment: you can create a Bitmap to get the picture like `Bitmap image1=new Bitmap(myUrl,true);` and set the picturebox image like `Image= image1;` Better explained in the documentation linked in the comment above.

Comment: Debug through, check the final complete image path, see if the file exists...

Answer (score 0):

1. Add PictureBox on the form
2. List item
3. Browse Image property
4. Resource Context
5. Import button
6. Chose Png file.

You can do it by code.

```
pictureBox1.Load(@"C:\Mine\download.png");
```

Comment: I need to do this all programmatically not through a toolbox since it is for a project.